# Program won't move onto next method

Tags: c#

My program won't move onto the next method after it executes the main method.
Right now, it just prints out "Hey! Welcome to Tina's Dice Game. Let's Start!", and then stops. How do I fix this? I've messed around with it for a while, but nothing worked. Thank you for your help.

```
using System;

namespace Major_Coding_Assignment_1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hey! Welcome to Tina's Dice Game.");
        Console.WriteLine("Let's start!");
    }
    public static int numberofInvokes = 0;
    public void EvenOrOdd()
    {
        numberofInvokes += 1;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        int y = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        int added = x + y;

        if (added % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I got" + " " + x + " " + "and" + " " + y);
            Console.WriteLine("Evens are better than odds.");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I got" + " " + x + " " + "and" + " " + y);
            Console.WriteLine("Odds are still cool!");
        }
    }
    public void playAgain()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again?");

        string val = Console.ReadLine();

        if (val == "yes")
        {
            EvenOrOdd();
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number of times the dice was thrown is:" + " " + numberofInvokes);
            Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing, come play again soon!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have to call some other method from main. Think about the flow: when the program starts, it calls main. Then in main you do 2 console writes, and that's it!, main is done, the program exits. There is no "automatic jump" to some other method, they must be called. Perhaps at the end of main, you meant to call the `EvenOrOdd` method after those console writes?

Comment: Or, put more simply, when your code executes the.last line of your `Main` method, it `returns`, exiting the program. Your Main calls`Console.WriteLine`. If you want it to do anything else, you need to call that `AnythingElse()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the methods you need from the main function like this...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hey! Welcome to Tina's Dice Game.");
    Console.WriteLine("Let's start!");
    EvenOrOdd();
    playAgain();
}
```

The better way is to call `playAgain` inside `EvenOrOdd` method to make things look cleaner.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hey! Welcome to Tina's Dice Game.");
    Console.WriteLine("Let's start!");
    EvenOrOdd();
}
public static int numberofInvokes = 0;
public void EvenOrOdd()
{
    numberofInvokes += 1;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int x = rnd.Next(1, 7);
    int y = rnd.Next(1, 7);
    int added = x + y;

    if (added % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I got" + " " + x + " " + "and" + " " + y);
        Console.WriteLine("Evens are better than odds.");
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I got" + " " + x + " " + "and" + " " + y);
        Console.WriteLine("Odds are still cool!");
    }
    playAgain(); //Call playAgain from here.
}
public void playAgain()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again?");

    string val = Console.ReadLine();

    if (val == "yes")
    {
        EvenOrOdd();
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The number of times the dice was thrown is:" + " " + numberofInvokes);
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing, come play again soon!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its important that you call your methods from main. I like to think of it like a recipe main is the first instruction but you need to tell the reader where to look next. The same is true for C#, you need to tell the compiler where to go next by calling the next function in the main one.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //your start code       
       nextFunction();
    }
 public void nextFunction(){
       //your next function code
}
```